# public func addObserver<T,M>(topic: T.Type,observer: M:T) {}

Tags: swift, generics

I want to define a method: the params are generics, the topic is a `Protocol`, and the observer must inherit from `Protocol`. The effect I want is like this, but it failed to compile.

```
public func addObserver<T,M>(topic: T.Type,observer: M:T) {}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A generic type cannot be a protocol, it can be a type which conforms to the protocol.

Comment: @vadian  I don't understand how to write it,can you write a demo?Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this? `protocol Topic {}; struct MyObserver: Topic {}; func add<M: Topic>(observer: M) {}; add(observer: MyObserver())`.

Comment: Assuming `T` is a generic type and the protocol is called `Topic` write `public func addObserver<T,M>(topic: T.Type,observer: M:Topic) where T:Topic {}`